# Primefaces 3.4 p:selectOneRadio value=null in p:ajax listener

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

The following code works in PF 3.2 but when I switched to 3.4 the SelectOneRadio value is always null? I've tried event as change and valueChange instead of default click, all results are the same value=null. Works in FF, IE8 hits the setComp method twice both null values if the p:ajax has an update to "main" p:panelGrid

```
 <p:panelGrid id="main" columns="1"  styleClass="Grid">
   <p:selectOneRadio id="newold" value="#{newmailer.selectedCompStatus}" >  
            <f:selectItems value="#{newmailer.options}" />  
            <p:ajax  listener="#{newmailer.setComp}"  update="main"   />
   </p:selectOneRadio>  
 </p:panelGrid>


    private List<SelectItem> options;


public NewMailerBean(){
    super();
    images = new ArrayList<byte []>();
    imagesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    SelectItem option = new SelectItem("exist", "Existing Company", "This        is for selectItems tag");  
    options.add(option);
    option = new SelectItem("new", "New Company");
    options.add(option);

}
 public void setComp(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {



    String str = this.selectedCompStatus;
    try {

          if(str.equals("exist")){

              setExist(true);
              setShowInfo(true);

          }else{

              setExist(false);
              setShowInfo(true);
          }
```

Comment: May I assume that those two `event.getSource()` and `test.getValue()` lines are a careless leftover of some experiment and that they do actually not belong to the real code? Please remove them from the question then to reduce code noise.

Comment: Yes, in 3.2 I was able to get the value of them also. I will remove them from this example.

Comment: Okay, coming back to the concrete problem. I can't reproduce this problem with PF 3.4.1. Surely the cause must be elsewhere. What type is the `options`? Is it `List<String>`/`String[]`? If a different type, do you have a `Converter` for that or what?

Comment: I edited the code section to show it's a List<SelectItem>. Also note it is inside p:wizard>>p:tab>>p:panel>>p:panelGrid>>p:fieldset

Comment: I have added the selectOneRadio tag to a test.xhtml with just a h:form, breakpoint in setComp gets hit twice (onClick) the first time the value is null the second time the value is set???

Comment: Works fine in FF 15.0.1 but unfortunately not in IE8 (company policy to use IE8)